# switch a branch in a remote git repository

Tags: git, githooks

when i deploy production code i simply do "git push production" - i have a post-receive hook that does this:

"git checkout -f" - that will update our production code with the latest push.

In this case, i'd like our production repo to be in another branch, is there any way to do that from a hook or a command from a local machine send to the remote repo?

I'm asking this because I'd like to restrict access to the live server. Currently the way this is done is we ssh to the live server, and do "git checkout .

Answer (score 0):

You can execute whichever script you like in post receive hook. 
Now - access, you may use SSH public key auth at best.